# GCM Messages not Being Delivered

Tags: c#, android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to deliver push messages via GCM to my Android device that I have connected locally to my desktop in Debug mode. I can register with GCM and get a registration ID back. However when I send a message from the server to GCM it never reaches my device. Any ideas what's missing here?

Here is the C# code I'm using to send the message to GCM:

```
                wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "key=" + senderAuthToken);
                var nameValues = new NameValueCollection
                                     {
                                         {"registration_id", registrationId},
                                         {"collapse_key", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                                         {"data.payload", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message)}
                                     };
                var resp = wc.UploadValues("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", nameValues);
                var respMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);
```

This is the response I get back from GCM:

**id=0:1345244000449737%276b04adef6fbb69**

So it looks like the message is authenticating and getting queued up in GCM.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fiserv.mobile.poc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission android:name="fiserv.mobile.poc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="fiserv.mobile.poc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 

<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />  

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="fiserv.mobile.poc" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

</application>
```

And here is my GCMIntentService.java service:

```
package fiserv.mobile.poc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.e("Registration", "Got an error!");
        Log.e("Registration", arg0.toString() + arg1.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.i("Registration", "Just registered!");
        Log.i("Registration", arg0.toString() + arg1.toString());   

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    }
}
```

And finally here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package fiserv.mobile.poc;

import fiserv.mobile.poc.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RegisterWithGCM();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void RegisterWithGCM()
    {           
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {

          Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
        }
    }

    String SENDER_ID = "158778556981";
}
```

I can see the log statements when I register with GCM, but I never hit the `onMessage` or see the log statement "Got a message!", no matter how many messages I send to GCM. I have verified I'm using the Service Key that matches the "Sender ID" I'm using in the Android application.

Any ideas why the messages are not being delivered?

Comment: I m facing same problem. I also checked in google api console page where it shows 0 messages, but I get successful response from GCM server. Not sure what the problem is, did it get solved for you ?

Comment: I have same problem. On SGS 2 (Android 4.0.4) which is connected to my Google Account I'm receiving messages. But on my gf's HTC Wildfire S (Android 2.3) I'm not receiving anything.

Registration ids are correct.

Comment: @vipsy make sure you have a Google account logged into to your device. I just got this working after updating my password on my phone. See my answer below.

Comment: @PaulFryer Thanks, I had that doubt, but my phone has always a working gmail account. Infact, I have 2 accounts added. Sync was off, but now I also have sync on still same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **have a Google account logged into your device**. The reason I wasn't getting notifications was because I had changed my Google (Gmail) password before I started testing the GMC stuff. After updating the password, I started getting notifications on my device.

On android 2.2 there was no "update password" button in the settings > account section. I had to go to the Play application then try downloading an app, then it asked for the new password.